# How Should I Prove that M is Torsion-free Given that M is Projective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, projective-module

**Question:**
R is an integral domain, M is a projective R-module and Tor(M) = {$x\in M$: rx = 0 for some non-zero $r\in R$}. Prove that M is torsion-free (i.e. Tor(M) = {$0_M$}).

**Attempt:**
I don't seem to know how to tackle this problem. I thought of a R-module homomorphism and surjective function $f: N\to M$. Since M is projective, then there exists the inverse $g:M\to N$. however, I couldn't justify introducing N, and I couldn't make progress as well.

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Recall: If $M$ is a projective $R$-module, then exists $R$-module $K$ s.t. the $R-$module $M\oplus K$ is free.

Comment: @Asigan Okay, but how do I use this fact to show that M is torsion-free?

Comment: Free modules are torsion free. Submodules of free modules are therefore also torsion free.

Comment: @MrProf $M\oplus K\cong \oplus_{i\in I} R$, and hence $M$ is module-isomorphic to a submodule of $ \oplus_{i\in I} R$. What do you say about a member $\{r_i\}_{i\in I}\in  \oplus_{i\in I} R$ s.t. exists $r$, $r\{r_i\}_{i\in I}=0$?

Comment: @Asigan Just to be sure I understand the hint, you mean M⊕K≅$R^n$, and that if the submodule of $R^n$ is torsion-free, then M is torsion-free. Is that what you mean? If not, could you give more details? Thanks.

Comment: @MrProf Except that $I$ the indexed set might not be finite, you correctly solve the problem. By the way it seems you are not using mathjax. `\cong` for "$\cong$" and `\oplus` for "$\oplus$".

Comment: @Asigan I am not sure I am confident about this. I know $R^n$ is free. However, what would be the submodule of $R^n$ in this case? How would I establish this submodule is   torsion-free? How should I introduce K (does K mean kernel here)? Thanks.

Comment: @MrProf Claim: $R$ is a ring with no zero divisor. $\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I} R$ is torsion free. Proof: If $r\ne 0$, $r\{r_i\}_{i\in I}=0$, then $\{rr_i\}_{i\in I}\overset{\text{by def}}{=} r\{r_i\}_{i\in I}=0\overset{\text{by def}}{=}\{0\}_{i\in I}\implies rr_i=0$ for all $i$. $r\ne 0\implies r_i=0$. This proves the claim.  (not finished)

Comment: Now since $M\overset{i}{\to}M\oplus K\overset{\varphi}{\to}{\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I} R}$ where $i$ is inclusion, $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, exists isomorphism $\psi: M\to A$, where $A=\varphi(i(M))$. If $R\ni r\ne 0$ $m\in M$, $rm=0$, then $0=\psi(0)=\psi(rm)=r\psi(m)\overset{\text{by our previous claim}}{\Longrightarrow}\psi(m)=0\implies m=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The map $\bigoplus_{x\in M} R \to M$ is surjective, hence there exists a section map going to other way which exhibits $M$ as a submodule of a free module. Since $R$ is an integral domain, any $R$-submodule of a free $R$-module is torsion-free.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand what you are saying (the notation thrown next to R seems to throw me off here), are you saying the map $f:R^n→M$ is surjective, and since M is projective, then the inverse of f exists (call it g), so that $g:M→R^n$? If that is the case, we will have g(M) as a submodule of $R^n$, not M. I would appreciate it if you could throw more light on this.

Comment: The notation $\bigoplus_{x\in M} R$ means the direct sum of copies of $R$. There is one copy of $R$ for each element in $M$. The map (which is called $f$ in your comment) is then defined on generators. We have $g(M)\cong M$ a submodule of $\bigoplus_{x\in M} R$, which is a free module. I hope this clarifies things a bit, cheers.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but how did we come about the fact that $g(M)\cong M$? Thanks.

Comment: Well, $g$ is a section of $f$, which means $f$ is a left inverse for $g$. In other words $g$ is injective.

Comment: How I missed that! thanks. There is one final piece to the puzzle for me: how do I prove the claim that a submodule of a free R-module is torsion-free? In other words, how do I prove that M is torsion-free once I show it is a submodule of $R^n$?

Comment: You should check on this website, there is at least one question that already answers this. Also, be careful, I do mean the direct sum ($\oplus$), not the direct product (you keep writing $R^n$).

Comment: So, I think my proof should look like this: Let the map $f:⨁_{x∈M}R→M$ be an R-module homomorphism and surjective. Since M is projective, then $g:M→⨁_{x∈M}R$ is injective. This means g(M) is isomorphic to M, which isa submodule of $⨁_{x∈M}R$. Since $⨁_{x∈M}R$ is free,then it is torsion-free. And since M is its submodule, then M is also torsion-free. Does this make sense?